# Customizing Springdocs/Swagger UI paths in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a very basic Spring Boot 3 service with OpenAPI documentation using Spring Initializr.

```
plugins {
  java
  id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.4"
  id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
}

dependencies {
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
  implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui:2.4.0")
  ...
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
```

These two URLs work:

- http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs (shows JSON)
- http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html (redirects to http://localhost:8080/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html)

However, because my app is behind a reverse proxy, I want to customize these URLs. Setting the following in my application.yaml file does not work:

```
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: '/api/admin/v3/api-docs'
  swagger-ui:
    config-url: '/api/admin/v3/api-docs/swagger-config'
    path: '/api/admin/swagger-ui.html'
```

These pages load but navigating to the swagger-ui page shows me the Petstore demo app instead of my own app's documentation. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I needed to add these configs instead:

```java
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: '/api/admin/v3/api-docs'
  swagger-ui:
    path: '/api/admin/swagger-ui.html'
    url: '/api/admin/v3/api-docs'
```

Importantly, I had to remove `springdoc.swagger-ui.config-url` and add `springdoc.swagger-ui.url`. The reason is that there's a check inside `org.springdoc.ui.AbstractSwaggerIndexTransformer.defaultTransformations()` like this:

```java
if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(swaggerUiConfig.getUrl()) && StringUtils.isEmpty(swaggerUiConfig.getConfigUrl())){
  html = setConfiguredApiDocsUrl(html);
}
```

Setting a url and not setting a config-url will trigger the logic needed to make this work.